# Which of the following Can be the set of all discontinuities?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a non-decreasing function. Which of the following Can be the set of all discontinuities?

1. $\mathbb Z$
2. $\mathbb N$
3. $\mathbb Q$
4. $\mathbb R$\ $\mathbb Q$

My Try

Considering step function. It is non decreasing. Its discontinuities are set $\mathbb Z$. Taking the same function and re-defining in the negative axis such a way that those portion is continuous will give 2. True. Taking Thomae function, I get function is discontinues at $\mathbb Q$. If $F$ would be monotone 4. won't be correct. But here $F$ is only not decreasing. I am confused. Please help me.

Comment: The Thomae function is not non-decreasing.

Comment: A monotone function can have only countable amount of discontinuities.

Comment: Sorry. Let me think another example.

Comment: @Jakobian But it is given that it is non-decreasing. So, $F$ can be increasing/any other function which is not decreasing. right?

Comment: @Truth_searcher No, non-decreasing means that $x< y \implies F(x)\leq F(y)$.

Comment: Sorry. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

For $1$ take the functions $f(x)=[x]$

For $2$ take the functions $f(x)=[x]$ if $x>\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

For $3$ let $\{q_1,...q_m...\}$ and enumeration of the rationals.

Then take $f(x)=\sum_{q_n<x}\frac{1}{n^2}$

For the last one it is proved that the set of discontinuities of a function is a countable union of closed sets.

By Baire's Category theorem the irrationals cannot be written as a countable union of closed sets.

So the only set that cannot be the set of all discontinuities of a functions is the set of irrationals.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers show that functions for (1)-(2)-(3) exist.

A function that satisfies (4) does not exist, since the discontinuities of a non-decreasing function form a countable set and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable.